# Search for project files in an Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'd like to parse specific files and present the parsed data in a table view in my Eclipse plugin. To get a hold on the files to parse, I'd like to make a query on all projects, something like `IProject.find("pom.xml")`
I've read about resources in the Plugin developer guide and I am able to work my way down to these files through Workspace > Projects > members > etc. but is there no Search-Service (something similar to what the Search dialog uses) I can include to get a collection of all files of a certain name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The File Search page uses `org.eclipse.search.ui.text.TextSearchQueryProvider` (for which there is very little documentation) but this is intended to be used with the `NewSearchUI` Search View interface.

Other than that there is no generic search code. You can use the `accept` methods of `IResource` to traverse resources (projects, folders and files). You will have to write you own code to search individual files.

Comment: With `TextSearchQueryProvider` being out-of-scope-ish, `accept` in conjunction with a Visitor implementation does the trick